# How can I save the generated PDF file into a variable with react-pdf library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

I used the react-pdf library for generating PDF files with dynamic data then I made an endpoint in my API for a sending part (I want to send the generated pdf file to the user's email address) but I would like to know how I can store the generated file on the frontend into a variable (so I can create an API call and send it). I know that for downloading I could just use the `PDFDownloadLink` component that comes from the library, but instead of downloading I want to store it in the variable.

This is the button that has the downloading component wrapped around so after clicking the user can download the file but I would want to send it on click instead.

```
<PDFDownloadLink
style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
document={<PDFFile\>}
>

<Button
css={{ width: '100%' }}
variant="option"
onClick={() => {}}
size={'large'}
>
{text}
</Button\>

</PDFDownloadLink\>
```

I would like to know how to save the generated file into a variable so I can work with it further on. I don't really know how to do it because all the examples I found with this library were for specifically downloading the file which I don't need.